# How to change POA to POS with babe?

Tags: substrate-node-template, consensus, babe, aura

How to change the the consensus of node-template from POA to POS with babe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have integrated the POS in fresh node-template on polkadot-v1.0.0

Here you can find the POS(proof-of-stake) node-template with babe: https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/POA-to-POS

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use nominated PoS consensus?