How to change a custom consensus of a parachain to PoS?
I am using this parachain repo. Where there is a custom consensus implemented.
How can I change the consensus from custom to PoS consensus?

There is a similar question related to this, you can check it here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/10153/4965
Or there is a very detailed explanation from Parity expert:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4910/4965
Hope it helps
